# Install New Cocoapods without changing existing Dependencies?

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

Working from an app that's pushing 8 years old now. Was written in Objective C. The podfile looks like this.

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.2.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.6'

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'MessageBanner', '~> 1.0'
```

I'd like to add new pods to the project. Namely, Stripe. Stripe runs successfully on my local machine from a different Xcode project that uses this podfile syntax.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Superapps' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3'
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'Cards'


end
```

Is there a way to run a terminal command that can add the new pods to the project while leaving the existing dependencies intact? Whenever `pod install` or `pod install --no-repo-update` is used after adding the new pods to the project, an eventual compiler warning `no such module stripe` is displayed by Xcode. Is there a way to fix this?

For the life of me, every edit that has been tried, including changes to the podfile and a slew of different terminal commands either produce an App project that can run the dependencies before the update but always the `no such module stripe` warning error. I've contacted Stripe, and am now in communication with Apple for their Code Level Support for the Apple developer program.

Note: Apple has expressed that their code level support only pertains to Apple frameworks...

Comment: when you run `pod install`, it will not update your dependencies and uses the `Podfile.lock` for existing onces.

Comment: You might just need a build after `pod install` to update the Xcode module cache